# "NetworkError: 404 Not Found" - $.post() with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is js code in our Rails 3.2 app responding to change of fields whose ids start with 'order_order_items_attributes':

```
$(function (){
    $(document).on('change', "[id^='order_order_items_attributes'][id$='_name']", function (){
    $.post(window.location, $('form').serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
});
```

The $.post() causes the error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://localhost:3000/po/orders/new?parent_record_id=4&parent_resource=ext_construction_projectx%2Fprojects&project_id=4%22"
```

Here is the `window.location`:
[image]

If we replace $.post() with $.get(), then the code works fine and fires up the ajax response on the server:

```
$.get(window.location, $('form').serialize(), null, "script");  #works!
```

But we have to use $.post() because of the large amount of data being posted to the server. The jquery document shows that $.get() and $.post() have exactly the same format. What we missed here with $.post()?

### Update

rake routes output:

```
Routes for PurchaseOrderx::Engine:
        search_order_items GET    /order_items/search(.:format)         purchase_orderx/order_items#search
search_results_order_items GET    /order_items/search_results(.:format) purchase_orderx/order_items#search_results
         stats_order_items GET    /order_items/stats(.:format)          purchase_orderx/order_items#stats
 stats_results_order_items GET    /order_items/stats_results(.:format)  purchase_orderx/order_items#stats_results
               order_items GET    /order_items(.:format)                purchase_orderx/order_items#index
                           POST   /order_items(.:format)                purchase_orderx/order_items#create
            new_order_item GET    /order_items/new(.:format)            purchase_orderx/order_items#new
           edit_order_item GET    /order_items/:id/edit(.:format)       purchase_orderx/order_items#edit
                order_item GET    /order_items/:id(.:format)            purchase_orderx/order_items#show
                           PUT    /order_items/:id(.:format)            purchase_orderx/order_items#update
                           DELETE /order_items/:id(.:format)            purchase_orderx/order_items#destroy
             search_orders GET    /orders/search(.:format)              purchase_orderx/orders#search
     search_results_orders GET    /orders/search_results(.:format)      purchase_orderx/orders#search_results
              stats_orders GET    /orders/stats(.:format)               purchase_orderx/orders#stats
      stats_results_orders GET    /orders/stats_results(.:format)       purchase_orderx/orders#stats_results
        event_action_order GET    /orders/:id/event_action(.:format)    purchase_orderx/orders#event_action
        acct_approve_order PUT    /orders/:id/acct_approve(.:format)    purchase_orderx/orders#acct_approve
         acct_reject_order PUT    /orders/:id/acct_reject(.:format)     purchase_orderx/orders#acct_reject
          gm_approve_order PUT    /orders/:id/gm_approve(.:format)      purchase_orderx/orders#gm_approve
           gm_reject_order PUT    /orders/:id/gm_reject(.:format)       purchase_orderx/orders#gm_reject
           gm_rewind_order PUT    /orders/:id/gm_rewind(.:format)       purchase_orderx/orders#gm_rewind
              submit_order PUT    /orders/:id/submit(.:format)          purchase_orderx/orders#submit
  list_open_process_orders GET    /orders/list_open_process(.:format)   purchase_orderx/orders#list_open_process
                    orders GET    /orders(.:format)                     purchase_orderx/orders#index
                           POST   /orders(.:format)                     purchase_orderx/orders#create
                 new_order GET    /orders/new(.:format)                 purchase_orderx/orders#new
                edit_order GET    /orders/:id/edit(.:format)            purchase_orderx/orders#edit
                     order GET    /orders/:id(.:format)                 purchase_orderx/orders#show
                           PUT    /orders/:id(.:format)                 purchase_orderx/orders#update
                           DELETE /orders/:id(.:format)                 purchase_orderx/orders#destroy
                      root        /                                     purchase_orderx/orders#index
```

Here is the rake routes output for purchase order engine. Most of the routes are not relevant to the question and still listed as it is.

here is routes.rb:

```
resources :order_items do
    collection do
      get :search
      get :search_results
      get :stats
      get :stats_results 
    end
  end

  resources :orders do
    collection do
      get :search
      get :search_results
      get :stats
      get :stats_results 
    end
    
  end
```

Workflow related actions were removed in routes.rb for easy read.

Comment: Did you try posting to create instead? Like - http://localhost:3000/po/orders/create?parent_record_id=4&parent_resource=ext_construction_projectx%2Fprojects&project_id=4%22"

Comment: You probably haven't specified the path as POST in your routes.rb. Can you show how your routes.rb looks like?

Comment: The post is to send the user input on the form to the server ajax. Server takes the user input and retrieves from database and insert on the form in some fields. Since users can dynamically add more fields to the form, the data posted back to server could be pretty large. That's why we want to use $.post instead of $.get.

Comment: Here is the declaration in routes.rb: resources :orders do .... end

Comment: Try adding this to your routes.rb - post '/po/orders/new', :controller => :orders, :action => :new

Comment: The above should prevent the 404 error, but I'm still not sure if that is what you need. 'new' is basically a GET request which posts to 'create' action. So technically, you should be posting to 'create' action

Comment: The 404 still exists. Added both post '/po/orders/new', :controller => :orders, :action => :new 
  post '/po/orders/edit', :controller => :orders, :action => :edit to engine's routes.rb. When posting back in editing (add new record), there is error: 

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://localhost:3000/po/orders/13/edit". We prefer a solution without specifying the mounting name of /po/ because the engine may be mounted as, ex /purchase_order/. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your backend routing is not properly routing that URL to a valid controller when using the POST HTTP verb.  In the root of your Rails project in the terminal, run `rake routes` to see all available routes, and where they end up.  Without seeing your `routes.rb` I can't explain exactly what's wrong, but it's definitely a backend routing issue.

I wouldn't recommend what some of the comments are saying, to just "stick this in routes.rb and it will work".  Your routes should be well maintained and using the correct Route helper for the job.  If you throw misc. routes in there to solve problems as they come up, you'll end up with a pile of spaghetti for your routing, and maintenance of your application will become more difficult over time.

*Edit: Updated to reference the update from the question*
The current page URL is `/po/orders/new`.  Looking at your `rake routes` output, this maps to `new_order_path`, evidenced by this row:

```
new_order GET    /orders/new(.:format)                 purchase_orderx/orders#new
```

If you look directly above it, you'll see the *real* route for the `create` action:

```
POST   /orders(.:format)                     purchase_orderx/orders#create
```

This `create` action is a `POST` to `orders_path`, which resolves as `/po/orders/`.  If you POST to this URL, everything should work.  If you want to be able to post to URL you're currently using and have it work, just modify your `routes.rb` to match this:

```
resources :order_items do
  collection do
    get :search
    get :search_results
    get :stats
    get :stats_results 
  end
end

resources :orders do
  # Manually route POSTs to /new to the create action
  post "/new", :controller => :orders, :action => :create

  collection do
    get :search
    get :search_results
    get :stats
    get :stats_results 
  end
end
```

Now, when you make a POST to this URL (`/po/orders/new`, it will hit the `OrdersController` `create` method. You can still hit this method by POSTing to `/po/orders` as well (as I recommended above).

Comment: Mike Trpcic, Please see updated post with routes.rb and rake routes. Also please be noted that the functionality of po is provided by a rails engine.

Comment: It makes sense!. In addition to the case of creating new order, editing order requires a post as well. What's the right URL for post when editing? Do we go with /po/order/id?

Comment: In Rails, editing is done with a "PUT" request.  You would make a PUT request to /po/order/:id.

Comment: Do we have to use 'put' for ajax editing? According to document, post can not do update.

Comment: By default, Rails will route POSTs to create, but you can put any manual routing into your hosts file.  I don't recommend doing this, as it breaks the RESTful nature of Rails.